# Positioning left/right toggle/trigger and corresponding menu of a dropdown menu

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to position left and right variations of a dropdown menu.

My problem is with the toggle(dropdown__toggle) I try to position right, but it doesn't work; I want the toggle to be above the menu triangle;

I use a position:relative for it, if I try position:absolute it's creating a mess.

I want the toggle and menu to not have a fixed width because I need to use it in multiple situations.

```css
.dropdown--right {
  position: relative; }
  .dropdown__toggle {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:right;
    position:relative;
    right:0;
    cursor: pointer; }
  .dropdown__menu {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    border-radius: 0.1875rem;
    color: #0b0b0b;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 4px 0 0 0; 
    min-width: 10rem;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-align: left;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 99; }
    .dropdown__menu__item {
      display: block;
      padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap; }

.dropdown__menu:after {
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: 100%;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0; }

.dropdown__menu:after {
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: 100%;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0; }
  .c-dropdown--right-triangle .c-dropdown__menu:before {
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: 100%;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    right: 16px;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    border-color: #BDBDBD transparent; }
.dropdown__menu::after {
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: 100%;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    right: 18px;
    border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
    border-color: #E3E3E3 transparent; }
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="dropdown--right" data-dropdown>
         <a class="dropdown__toggle" >Toggle</a>
        <ul class="dropdown__menu" data-dropdown-menu>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what you want to happen. `dropdown__toggle` is a div and it's width is 100% of it's parent; in that case `right: 0` is working exactly as it should.

Comment: @chazsolo - I want toggle to be above the menu triangle; now is on the left; dropdown__toggle is an anchor(can be a span/button) not a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some styling and a class so you can use `dropdown--left` or `dropdown--right` to choose the display of your dropdown:

```css
/* COMMON STYLE */

.dropdown__toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown__menu {
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  color: #0b0b0b;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  min-width: 10rem;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.dropdown__menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown__menu::after {
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: 100%;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-color: #E3E3E3 transparent;
}


/* LEFT STYLE */

.dropdown--left {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown--left .dropdown__menu {
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.dropdown--left .dropdown__menu::after {
  left: 18px;
}


/* RIGHT STYLE */

.dropdown--right {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}

.dropdown--right .dropdown__menu {
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown--right .dropdown__menu::after {
  right: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="dropdown--left" data-dropdown>
    <a class="dropdown__toggle">Toggle</a>
    <ul class="dropdown__menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div>
  <div class="dropdown--right" data-dropdown>
    <a class="dropdown__toggle">Toggle</a>
    <ul class="dropdown__menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the class `dropdown--right` to also align the text in `dropdown__toggle` to the right, I think all you need is to include `text-align`.

```
.dropdown--right {
     position: relative;
     text-align: right;  <-- Added CSS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to be using this dropdown menu in multiple situations/components, I think it's as simple as adding `position: absolute;` and `right: 0;` to the `.dropdown--right` element, because you're going to be using it in other html elements anyway. And then for the left version of this component it'll be as easy as replacing the `right: 0;` with `left: 0;`

```
<div class="dropdown__containerexample">
  <div class="dropdown--right" data-dropdown>
     <a class="dropdown__toggle" >Toggle</a>
     <ul class="dropdown__menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a>Cameras</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-css -->

  .dropdown__containerexample {
     position: relative;
     width: 50%;
     height: 200px;
     border: 1px solid #000; } 
  .dropdown--right {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; }
  .dropdown__toggle {
    cursor: pointer; }
  .dropdown__menu {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    border-radius: 0.1875rem;
    color: #0b0b0b;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 4px 0 0 0; 
    min-width: 10rem;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-align: left;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 99; }
    .dropdown__menu__item {
      display: block;
      padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap; }
.dropdown__menu::after {
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: 100%;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    right: 18px;
    border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
    border-color: #E3E3E3 transparent; }
```

Comment: absolute is not working, because menu is also absolute , and create multiple issues